IPA application opens links in Edge browser instead of Safari browser
I am developing iOS application which is installed in my iPad device. I have introduced 1 hyperlink in that application which should be opened in Safari browser of iPad. I have Microsoft Edge installed in iPad also and have set default browser as Safari from Edge itself. But still the hyperlink from my application gets opened in Edge browser only. I dont see any option to set default browser as Safari from Safari application itself (like i can see it from Edge) through Settings option of iPad device. My application is not registered in App Store yet as its under development stage yet.
How shall i redirect and open hyperlink in Safari browser though Edge or any other browsers are installed in iPad device?

Can anyone provide solution to this issue?
